# My DIV sits on top of the previous DIV

Tags: html, css

I have just started putting my site together. I have a scrolling banner DIV and now i want to add a an image underneath 'largemenubutton' DIV but when I place it just sits on top of my banner? I have put in the CSS to clear:left however this does not work.

**html**

```
       <body>
        <div class="mainhome">
            <div class="header">
              <div class="menubutton-leftside" style="margin-right:23px"><h2>home</h2></div>
              <div class="menubutton-leftside" style="margin-right:20px"><h2>about</h2></div>
              <div class="menubutton-leftside" style="margin-right:30px"><h2>portfolio</h2></div>
              <div class="menubutton-leftside" style="margin-right:27px"><h2>contact</h2></div>
                <div class="logo"><img src="images/es-logo.png" width="170" height="170" /></div> 
              <div class="menubutton-rightside" style="margin-left:17px"><h2>print</h2></div>
              <div class="menubutton-rightside" style="margin-left:25px"><h2>digital</h2></div>
              <div class="menubutton-rightside" style="margin-left:38px"><h2>illustration</h2></div>
              <div class="menubutton-rightside" style="margin-left:20px"><h2>brand</h2></div>
          </div>
                <div class="mainimage">
                <div id="slider_container">
          <div id="slides">
                        <img src="images/slider/emmasteed.png" alt="Emma Steed Graphic Art and Web Design" />
                        <img src="images/slider/graphicdesign-desk.png" alt="Emma Steed Graphic Art and Web Design" />
          </div>
        </div>
    <div class="bluebar"></div></div>
                <div class="largemenubutton"><img src="images/portfolio.png" /></div>
        </div>
```

**css**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-image:url(images/header-background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin:0;
}

.mainhome {
    width: 855px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.header {
    height: 236px;
    background-image:url(images/header-background.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    clear:left;
}

.mainimage {
    width: 855px;
    height: 423px;
    background-color:#0C9;
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    z-index:-1;
}

#slider_container {
        width:855px;
        height:423px;
        overflow:hidden;
}

.bluebar {
    width: 855px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color:#334d5c;
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}

.menubutton-leftside {
    width:60px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:95px;
}

.menubutton-rightside {
    width:60px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:95px;
    text-align:right;
}

h2 {
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#666;
    display:inline;
}

.logo {
    width:170px;
    height:170px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:30px;
}

.largemenubutton {
    width:261px;
    height:259px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```

JSFIDDLE here
http://jsfiddle.net/cX8Z9/

Comment: Hello, it would help if you added an example using jsfiddle that we can use to see and try to fix your problem! http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is an extra `</div>` after the `bluebar`, so the `largemenubutton` is not inside the same container `mainimage`, which is positioned absolutely (so the `largemenubutton` is just sitting where it would sit if the `mainimage` hadn't been there at all).

```html
<div class="bluebar"></div></div>
<div class="largemenubutton"><img src="images/portfolio.png" /></div>
```

And you can't "clear" an absolute positioning the way you can a float.
So the solution is to move the offending `</div>` two lines down, thus putting the `largemenubutton` inside the `mainmenu`.

```html
<div class="bluebar"></div>
<div class="largemenubutton"><img src="images/portfolio.png" /></div>
</div>
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/8GH5F/1/).